# Size of minimal families of $k$-element subsets that cannot be met by a $k$-element subset simultaneously

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

What is the minimal size of a set $\mathfrak S$ of $k$-element subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that for any $k$-element subset $S$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ there is an $S'\in\mathfrak S$ with $S\cap S'=\varnothing$?

As shown in an answer and comments to it, for $n<2k$ there are no such $\mathfrak S$, for $n=2k$ the only possibility is to take for $\mathfrak S$ all $k$-element subsets, so that in this case the answer is $\binom{2k}k$, while for $n\geqslant (k+1)k$ one can (and must at least) take any $k+1$ pairwise disjoint $k$-element subsets and the answer is $k+1$. Thus the cases $2k<n<(k+1)k$ remain unsolved.

As suggested in a comment below: in case this is very hard, - mainly I would like to know this in the case $n=3k$.

Here are some calculations (being updated using the accepted answer): denoting by $\mu(n,k)$ the minimal size of $\mathfrak S$ as above,
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mu(\geqslant2,1)=2&\mu(4,2)=6&\mu(6,3)=20&\mu(8,4)=70&\mu(10,5)=252\\ &\mu(5,2)=4&\mu(7,3)=12&\mu(9,4)=30&\mu(11,5)\leqslant113\\
&\mu(\geqslant6,2)=3&\mu(8,3)=8&\mu(10,4)\leqslant21&\mu(12,5)\leqslant72\\
&&\mu(9,3)=7&\mu(11,4)\leqslant18&\mu(13,5)\leqslant54\\
&&\mu(10,3)=6&\mu(12,4)=12&\mu(14,5)\leqslant42\\
&&\mu(11,3)=5&\mu(13,4)\leqslant14&\mu(15,5)\leqslant31\\
&&\mu(\geqslant12,3)=4&\mu(14,4)\leqslant12&\mu(16,5)\leqslant28\\
&&&\mu(15,4)\leqslant10&\mu(17,5)\leqslant26\\
&&&\mu(16,4)\leqslant9&\mu(18,5)\leqslant24\\
&&&\mu(17,4)\leqslant8&\mu(19,5)\leqslant22\\
&&&\mu(18,4)\leqslant7&\mu(20,5)\leqslant20\\
&&&\mu(19,4)\leqslant6&\mu(21,5)\leqslant18\\
&&&\mu(\geqslant20,4)=5&\mu(22,5)\leqslant17\\
&&&&\mu(23,5)\leqslant16\\
&&&&\mu(24,5)\leqslant14\\
&&&&\mu(25,5)\leqslant12\\
&&&&\mu(26,5)\leqslant10\\
&&&&\mu(27,5)\leqslant9\\
&&&&\mu(28,5)\leqslant8\\
&&&&\mu(29,5)\leqslant7\\
&&&&\mu(\geqslant30,5)=6
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: I doubt there is a nice explicit formula. Are you looking for approximate estimates, or upper bounds, or lower bounds?

Comment: @CalvinLin Well I was hoping for explicit constructions of minimal $\mathfrak S$. My main interest is the case $n=3k$.

Comment: If you have a main interest, you should write that in. I do believe that the general case is much more complicated.

Comment: @CalvinLin You seem to be right, will do it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something... isn't a minimal such family the empty set? Are you looking for a maximal family? Or, if you are looking for a non-empty solution, isn't $\{\{1, ..., k\}, \{k+1, ..., 2k\}\}$ always such a family as well?

Comment: @roundsquare The empty $\mathfrak S$ won't do since for every $k$-element $S$ one must find certain $S'\in\mathfrak S$. As for $\{\{1,...,k\},\{k+1,...,2k\}\}$, it does not work since e. g. for $S=\{2,...,k,k+1\}$ it does not contain any $S'$ with $S\cap S'=\varnothing$.

Comment: @roundsquare Probably you thought that $S$ must be taken from $\mathfrak S$, actually it is arbitrary. I have added this to the question.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe At least for $n=7$, $k=3$ one can do better as there is an $\mathfrak S$ with 12 elements while $\binom63=20$: for example,$$\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,4,6\},\{1,5,6\},\{1,5,7\},\{2,3,6\},\{2,4,5\},\{2,4,7\},\{2,6,7\},\{3,5,7\},\{3,6,7\},\{4,5,6\}\}$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე got it, my mistake.

Comment: This problem looks like it will be very similar to block designs and/or transversal designs. Perhaps there is a solution involving them?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe It might be that the minimal $\mathfrak S$s have tendency to exhibit much symmetry (being "very special") and thus forming some kind of known block design. However in the example I gave there is some imbalance - all elements except 6 belong to 5 blocks, while 6 belongs to 6 blocks. Also, the pairs $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,5\}$, $\{5,3\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{4,7\}$, $\{7,1\}$, belong to a unique block, while all other pairs belong to exactly two blocks. Thus this $\mathfrak S$ tries to be very symmetric but fails on account of one "bad" element somehow.

Comment: For n=7, k=3, you can take the 7 sets in the Fano plane. That has a ton of symmetry. I believe that is the best.

Comment: More generally, you are looking at the Kesnar graph and finding a vertex cover for the edges.

Comment: @CalvinLin If you mean the lines of the Fano plane, this won't work since any two of them meet at a point, so if $S$ is one of these lines, there is no other line $S'$ with $S\cap S'=\varnothing$.

Comment: What might work though is to take some *affine* plane and take for $\mathfrak S$ a set of lines that contains one from each system of parallel lines. But, if I am not mistaken, this will give the case you already mentioned before, with $n=k(k+1)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin As for Kesnar graphs, I never heard of them. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: The correct spelling is [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph).

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks a lot! This clarifies everything!

Comment: @CalvinLin Indeed the [Wikipedia page for Kneser graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph) seems to contain complete answer. It is stated there that the independence number of $KG_{n,k}$ is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, so its minimum vertex cover size must be $\binom nk-\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}k$. Following the literature I am sure one can construct explicit minimum vertex covers. Could you write an answer?

Comment: Alas, this is not quite what we need. A vertex cover is a set of vertices such that each edge has a vertex in this set. Whereas we need a set of vertices such that each vertex is connected by an edge to some vertex in this set. Does anybody know what is this called?

Comment: Terminology seems to be that we are looking for minimum [total dominating sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Variants) in Kneser graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $k$-subset $i$ is selected.  For each $i$, let $N_i$ denote the $k$-subsets that do not intersect $i$. The problem is to minimize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to linear constraints:
$$\sum_{j\in N_i} x_j \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $k$-subsets $i$}$$
The first several values of $\mu(3k,k)$ satisfy:
\begin{align}
\mu(3,1) &= 2\\
\mu(6,2) &= 3\\
\mu(9,3) &= 7\\
\mu(12,4) &= 12\\
15 \le \mu(15,5) &\le 29
\end{align}
For example, one optimal solution for $(9,3)$ consists of the seven 3-subsets $\{7,112,152,200,296,336,416\}$, with the following binary representations:

```
000000111
001110000
010011000
011001000
100101000
101010000
110100000
```

Comment: Thank you! Although not a complete answer, I am now convinced that this is sort of best one can do. May I ask you which software did you use?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I used the OPTMODEL procedure in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

If $k>\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ then $\mathfrak S$ cannot exist.

If $k=1$, then $|\mathfrak S| \le 2$. Example: $\mathfrak S = \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$

If $k=2$, then $|\mathfrak S| \le 6$. Example: $\mathfrak S = \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\}$

In general, for $k\le \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$, I believe you need $|\mathfrak S| \le \dbinom{2k}{k}$.

Edit: As Calvin Lin suggested, you also have:

$$k+1 \le |\mathfrak S| \le \dbinom{2k}{k}$$

Comment: I think I understand the question now.

Comment: It depends on $n$. For example, if $n\geqslant6$ then for $k=2$ the answer is 3  since $\mathfrak S=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ works for all such $n$.

Comment: For $k=2$, if $ n \geq k(k+1) = 6$, then we can take $ \{ 1,2 \}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\}$. Any $k$ element subset can only intersect at most $k$ of these disjoint subsets, so there is 1 that it doesn't intersect. This is also the best that we can do, so the interesting case is when $ k(k+1) > n $

Comment: @CalvinLin Only two seconds late :)

Comment: Sorry, I swapped the direction of all of my inequalities by accident.